# how to get html of the checkbox whose property is checked

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes. When someone clicks on one of them. I need to send the html of the list of checkboxes to some other function where i can check which checkboxes are checked already.

My each checkbox has the class of "indicators".

```
                $('.indicators').each(function(){
                    alert($(this).prop('name');
                });
```

The above code correctly alerts the names of checkboxes checked. 
But later when i try to alert the whole html, the checkboxes seem to be unchecked.

Comment: You have a syntax error in that code. Why send the actual html to another function? Would you like to explain the bigger picture, I suspect there may be a far more succinct way to do what you want.

Comment: You don't need to send the HTML to any function - you can use the DOM to find out which checkboxes are checked. Can you please post your HTML so we can see how you've structured your page.

Comment: after checking the checkboxes, the whole div in which they exist would be refreshed. So I need to display the checkboxes along with their previous properties.

Comment: Checkboxes don't have any HTML. Strictly speaking, no DOM element has any HTML. What is returned by `element.innerHTML`, or the jQuery equivalent, is entirely synthetic.

Comment: this is the whole html http://jsfiddle.net/2e4Jc/

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot, so how to solve my problem, when the div is refreshed, I need to again replicate all the checkboxes which are checked/unchecked and write them back to the same div

Comment: what's the backend language?

Comment: These days, you would typically work within a single page that doesn't get refreshed. Send data to the server in an ajax request then, if necessary, update the document when the ajax response arrives. That way, as much of the original document as you need (including the checkboxes) is still there in the browser window. Many good ajax tutorials exist on the web.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot, this is a chart so the need

Answer (score 1):

i dont get why you want to send the html of all the checkboxes. in general you will need some attributes or validate if that checkbox is check it. if you need some attribute of the input that is checked and send to the function ...  that will be some thing like this

```
$('.indicators').click(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked')){
    alert('the checkbox ' + $(this).attr('name')+  ' is checked');
  }
});
```

but if you need really need the html you just change $(this).attr('name') for this $(this).html(). and if you need to send the html of all the checkboxes you will ouse the same but in one cycle

```
$('.indicators').each(function(){
  //some code
});
```